# mailto link does not insert email address to mail form on iOS

Tags: html, ios

My mailto link works well on Windows desktop but does not work with iOS. I does open the mail app but does not insert the email address to "To" section. Here's my html:

```
<div class="email">
  <span class="info-ico"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  <a class="txt" href="mailto:test@test.test">test@test.test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317431/i-cant-get-mailto-links-to-open-the-mail-app-from-mobile-safari-when-using-jqto) for a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't get mailto links to open the Mail app from Mobile Safari when using jQTouch. What could be wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317431/i-cant-get-mailto-links-to-open-the-mail-app-from-mobile-safari-when-using-jqto)

Comment: No, my case is different: i can open the mail app on iOS when clicking the mailto link

Comment: Sorry about that. My mistake. When I tried out your [code](http://ericwiener.xyz/test.html) it worked on both iOS and desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
<div class="email">
  <span class="info-ico"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  <a class="txt" href="mailto://test@test.test">test@test.test</a>
</div>
```

I've had this problem before and the `//` fixed it.