# Facing issue of // being append to recepient email while using mailto in html in ios

Tags: ios, hyperlink, mailto

I am writing a react app and I use to run it on Android and IOS as a web view.
I'm using a hyperlink for rendering my email adderess in the about section.
I wants that when user clicks on that email, the email app installed in the device should get open and the recepient input should get prefilled with the email that user has clicked on. My code is working fine on web and Android.

Here is how my code looks like -

```
<a href="mailto:example@gmail.com" target="_blank">
  example@gmail.com
</a>
```

In IOS particularly the `//` is getting appended to the front of recipeint mail in an email app when I am trying to use an `<a>` tag with `mailto:example.gmail.com`

I have tried adding `target="_blank"` after going through the following question but no suggestion worked for me -
[I can't get mailto links to open the Mail app from Mobile Safari when using jQTouch. What could be wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317431/i-cant-get-mailto-links-to-open-the-mail-app-from-mobile-safari-when-using-jqto)

The required behaviour is, when user clicks on email hyperlink, the mail app would get open and proper email should get prefilled in recepient field.